# Telerik reporting. VS. How to convert DateTime paremeter to ShortDateString in textbox?

Tags: c#, parameters, telerik-reporting

I have code in the textbox:

```
{Parameters.dtFrom} - {Parameters.dtTo}
```

But it displayed not as I need:

01.01.2014 00:00:00 - 12.12.2014 00:00:00

How can I convert that DateTime values to ShortDateString (01.01.2014 - 12.12.2014)

Thanks for help.

p.s. sorry for my bad english

Comment: Did you try to format them with `.ToString(string)`? Or using `ToShortDateString` method?

Comment: Of course! {Parameters.dtFrom.ToShortDateString()} returns error. And {Parameters.dtFrom}.ToShortDateString() returns text "myvaluetext.ToShortDateString()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the Format text function to do this, see [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/expressions-text-functions.html).

Then you could do something like the following

```
var textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Value = "=Format('{0:dd.mm.yyyy}', Parameters.dtFrom) - Format('{0:dd.mm.yyyy}', Parameters.dtTo)";
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert that `DateTime` values to `ShortDateString`: `Convert.ToDateTime(datepickerId.SelectedDate).ToShortDateString();`